# in Python, how to convert list of float numbers to string with certain format?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a list of tuple of float numbers, something like

```
[ (1.00000001, 349183.1430, 2148.12222222222222), ( , , ), ..., ( , ,) ]
```

How can I convert all numbers to strings, with same format (scientific notation with 8 decimal point precision), while maintaining the same structure (list of tuples, or list of lists)?

I think I can do it with nested for loops, but is there a simpler way such as using `map` somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by shape? Do you have a list of tuples or something? It would help if you showed an example of data and desired behavior.

Comment: If it's "shaped" `(m, n)`, it's a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have some list-of-lists or list-of-tuples:

```
lst = [ [ 1,2,3 ], [ 1e6, 2e6, 3e6], [1e-6, 2e-6, 3e-6] ]
```

You can create a parallel list-of-lists using list comprehension:

```
str_list = [['{0:.8e}'.format(flt) for flt in sublist] for sublist in lst]
```

Or a list-of-tuples:

```
str_list = [tuple('{0:.8e}'.format(flt) for flt in sublist) for sublist in lst]
```

Then, if you'd like to display this set of numbers:

```
str_display = '\n'.join(' '.join(lst) for lst in strlist)
print str_display
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to preserve a list of tuples, it's the same thing, just with `tuple('{..}'.. for flt in sublist)` instead.

Comment: Note that the inner list in the `join` is not needed.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, it [seems needed to me](http://ideone.com/W6gHsh). What would you put in place of the `join` expression?

Comment: @Rob: `print '\n'.join(' '.join(lst) for lst in strlist)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Ah, I see. I misunderstood your original comment. Agreed, the list is not needed. I have edited my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
a = [ (2.3, 2.3123), (231.21, 332.12) ]
p = list()
for b in a:
    k = list()
    for c in b:
        k.append("{0:.2f}".format(c))
    p.append(tuple(k))
print p
```

remove inner loop:

```
p = list()
for b in a:
    p.append(tuple("{0:.2f}".format(c) for c in b))
```

remove outer loop also:

```
p = [ tuple("{0:.2f}".format(c) for c in b) for b in a ]
```

to print `p`:

```
"\n".join([ "\t".join(b) for b in p ])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy you could do it this way:

```py
>>> a=[[11.2345, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 61234123412341234]]
>>> numpy.char.mod('%14.8E', a)

array([['1.12345000E+01', '2.00000000E+00', '3.00000000E+00'],
      ['4.00000000E+00', '5.00000000E+00', '6.12341234E+16']],
      dtype='|S14')
```

The datatype in the numpy array of strings is given as S14 which [according to the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) is a string (S) of 14 byte length.

Comment: I see. But that doesn't give me the string in scientific notation, does it?

Comment: sorry corrected it and this is probably the most compact (and fastest) of the lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use map, you can do something like this:

```
map(lambda x: tuple(map(lambda y: '%08f' % y, x)), list)
```

But IMO, the list comprehension is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A handy function:

```
def stringify(listAll, sFormat):
    listReturn = []
    for xItem in listAll:
        if type(xItem) == float:
            xNewItem = sFormat.format(xItem)
            print(type(xNewItem))
            listReturn.append(xNewItem)
        else:
            xNewItem = str(xItem)
            print(type(xNewItem))
            listReturn.append(xNewItem)
    return listReturn

listAll = ['a', 3.1, 'b', 2.6, 4, 5, 'c']
listNew = stringify(listAll, '{0:.3}')
print(listNew)
```

Take out the prints before using, etc.  I made it a bit verbose so you can see how it works, then tighten the code yourself.